# How to destroy a window after opening a new one?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a game called 'Flag Quiz' using tkinter. I have a script called `mainmenu` where I can choose between an easy mode and a hard mode. If I click on one of the buttons the recent `mainmenu` window disappears and a new tkinter window opens.

Here is my `mainmenu` script:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from hardmode import HardApp
from easymode import EasyApp

class TitleScreen(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Flag Quiz')
        self.geometry('600x600')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.make_widgets()



    def make_widgets(self):
        self.background = PhotoImage(file = './background.png')
        self.label = Label(self, image=self.background)
        self.label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.easy = Button(self, text="Easy Mode", height=2, width=6, font=('default', 20), command=self.play_easy)
        self.hard = Button(self, text="Hard Mode", height=2, width=6, font=('default', 20), command=self.play_hard)
        self.easy.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)
        self.hard.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)

    def play_easy(self):
        self.withdraw()
        self.app = EasyApp()
        #self.app.start()

    def play_hard(self):
        self.withdraw()
        self.app = HardApp()
        #self.app.start()




    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()

TitleScreen().start()
```

And here is my easy mode script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
import os
import json

class EasyApp(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Flag Quiz')
        self.geometry('')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.score = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # variables
        self.user_guess = StringVar(self)
        self.text = StringVar(self)
        self.text.set(" ")

        # initial image
        self.scoretext = Label(self, text="Score: ").pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.scorevalue = Label(self, text=self.score).pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.file = random.choice(os.listdir('pngs'))
        self.randimg = PhotoImage(file='pngs/{}'.format(self.file))
        self.randimg = self.randimg.subsample(2, 2)
        self.panel = Label(self, image=self.randimg)
        self.panel.pack()

        self.country, self.ext = self.file.split('.')
        self.countries = self.load_lookup()
        self.countryname = [country for country in self.countries if country['alpha2'] == self.country]

        self.s = []
        for i in range(0,3):
            country = random.choice(self.countries)
            self.s.append(country['de'])

        self.s.append(self.countryname[0]['de'])
        random.shuffle(self.s)

        self.btndict = {}
        for i in range(4):
            self.btndict[self.s[i]] = Button(self, text=self.s[i], height=2, width=35, font=('default', 20), command=lambda j=self.s[i]: self.check_input(j))
            self.btndict[self.s[i]].pack()


    def check_input(self, d):
        if d != self.countryname[0]['de']:
            print("Falsch")
        else:
            self.score += 5
            for widget in self.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            self.create_widgets()



    def load_lookup(self):
        with open('lookup.json') as file:
            self.obj = file.read()

        self.countryobj = json.loads(self.obj)
        return self.countryobj

    # def start(self):
    #     self.mainloop()
```

After clicking the close button (the default button on windows/osx to close a window) the window from my easy mode app disappears but PyCharm says that my program is still running.

I made some investigations and removed the `self.withdraw()` function in the function `play_easy(self)` in my mainmenu script. So now the mainmenu is still open after I click on the easy mode button. If I'm closing both windows now, the program fully ends.
Replacing `self.withdraw()` with `self.destroy()` is not working. The main menu is closed, but a new empty window opens instead.

Any suggestions on how to handle this problem so that my program fully ends if I click the close button within the easy/hard mode window?

Comment: you should send main window (root) to `EasyApp` as argument `EasyApp(self)` and assing to variable `self.root = root` and later run `self.root.destroy()`. But it may need also to use `root.wm_xxxx("DESTROY_WINDOW")` to assing function to `closing button` and run `root.destroy()`

Comment: you doesn't destroy main window but only hide it - and when you close `Toplevel` then it will not destroy it automatically but you have to assign function and run `destroy` to remove it. OR you should run self.destroy()` before you run `EasyApp()` - but then `EasyApp` should use `tk.Tk` instead of `tk.Toplevel`

Comment: @furas: "assing" → "assigning".

Comment: The architecture you have makes doing what you want awkward. I suggest making all windows `Toplevel`s and having an independent `root = Tk()` (which is hidden/withdrawn).

Comment: @furas your suggestion with destroy and changing EasyApp from tk.Toplevel to tk.Tk was the first attempt and it worked perfect. Thank you for that. Please write a answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @martineau thank you for your comment too. I try your suggestion as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two windows - main window created with `Tk` and subwindow created with `Toplevel`. When you use `close button` to close main window then it should also close all subwindows but when you close subwindow then it doesn't close main window (parent window) but only own subwindows - because usually it can be useful to display again main window to select other options and open again subwindow.

---

One of the methods is to `destroy` first window and use `Tk` to create new window.

But in this method you can't use some button in second window to go back to first window - and sometimes it can be problem. Even if you create again first window then it will not remeber previous values (if you have some `Entry` or other widgets to set values)

```
# from tkinter import *  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred`
import tkinter as tk

class EasyApp(tk.Tk):  # use `Tk` instead of `Toplevel`

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scoretext = tk.Label(self, text="EasyApp")
        self.scoretext.pack()

    #def start(self):
    #    self.mainloop()

class TitleScreen(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Easy Mode", command=self.play_easy)
        self.button.pack()

    def play_easy(self):
        self.destroy()  # destroy current window
        self.app = EasyApp()

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()

TitleScreen().start()
```

---

Other method is to use `self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)` to execute function `on_close` when you use `close button` and in this function `destroy` main window (`master`).

This way you can still use `Button` to go back to main window which will remember previous content.

```
# from tkinter import *  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred`
import tkinter as tk

class EasyApp(tk.Toplevel):  # still use `Toplevel`

    def __init__(self, master):  # send main window as master/parent
        super().__init__(master)  # it will also set `self.master = master`
        
        self.scoretext = tk.Label(self, text="EasyApp")
        self.scoretext.pack()
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Go Back", command=self.go_back)
        self.button.pack()

        # run `on_close` when used `close button`
        #self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        
    def go_back(self):
        self.destroy()           # destroy only current window
        self.master.deiconify()  # show again main window

    def on_close(self):
        self.destroy()         # destroy current window
        self.master.destroy()  # destroy main window
        
class TitleScreen(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.insert('end', "You can change text")
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Easy Mode", command=self.play_easy)
        self.button.pack()

    def play_easy(self):
        self.withdraw()  
        self.app = EasyApp(self)  # send main window as argument

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()

TitleScreen().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple architecture for doing what you want. An application class is derived from `Tk()` which hides the default "root" window it normally displays and all the windows it does display are subclasses of a custom `Toplevel` subclass I've named `BaseWin`.

This class is just a `Toplevel` with its protocol for being delete (closed) set to call an a method named `on_close()`. This additional method simply destroys the current window before quits the application's `mainloop()` causing it to terminate.

The first window—an instance of the `TitleScreen` class—is displayed automatically when an instance of the application class is created. This window has two `Button`s one labelled <kbd>Easy Mode</kbd> and the other <kbd>Hard Mode</kbd>. When one of them is clicked, an instance of the appropriate `Toplevel` subclass is created after the current window is removed by it call its `destroy()` method.

#### `mainmenu.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from basewin import BaseWin
from easymode import EasyApp
from hardmode import HardApp


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Flag Quiz')
        self.geometry('600x600')
        self.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold")
        self.withdraw()  # Hide default root Tk window.
        startpage = TitleScreen(self.master)
        self.mainloop()


class TitleScreen(BaseWin):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.make_widgets()

    def make_widgets(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the Start Page", font=self.master.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.easy = tk.Button(self, text="Easy Mode", font=('default', 20),
                              command=self.play_easy)
        self.hard = tk.Button(self, text="Easy Mode", font=('default', 20),
                              command=self.play_hard)
        self.easy.pack()
        self.hard.pack()

    def play_easy(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = EasyApp(self.master)

    def play_hard(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = HardApp(self.master)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp()
```

#### `basewin.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *


class BaseWin(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

    def on_close(self):
        self.destroy()      # Destroy current window
        self.master.quit()  # Quit app.
```

#### `easymode.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *
from basewin import BaseWin


class EasyApp(BaseWin):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title('Flag Quiz')
        self.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
        self.make_widgets()

    def make_widgets(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the Easy App", font=self.master.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
```

#### `hardmode.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *
from basewin import BaseWin


class HardApp(BaseWin):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title('Flag Quiz')
        self.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
        self.make_widgets()

    def make_widgets(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the Hard App", font=self.master.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
```